# Cross-product matrix in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, cross-product

Is there a ready function or method in Eigen for the [Hat operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hat_operator#Cross_product)? That is the operator, taking a vector as input and returning a matrix, which mimics a cross product with that vector. I know, that it can be easily written, but would like to avoid it:

```
Eigen::Vector3d t = // some vector ;
Eigen::Matrix3d t_hat;
t_hat << 0, -t(2), t(1),
    t(2), 0, -t(0),
    -t(1), t(0), 0;
```

Comment: That matrix is usually called _antisymmetric_ or _skew-symmetric_ matrix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you noted both [cross](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1VectorwiseOp.html#a93a7a9d23fc28219f5dd82f3f90222ca) and the [cross3](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#aa74b2131193df7ff5590099b8db634af) methods actually perform the multiplication. But you want to make the [skew-symmetric matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix) representation of `t`.

What you have seems like the best you can do for `Vector3d` and `Matrix3d`. Generalizing for various types of `t` will require more time than I have right now, but it is an interesting question, so I may investigate later.